# How to generate link to restore password using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actionmailer, mailcatcher

I am using Mailer and MailCatcher.

When an admin registered the customer in the system, the customer should receive an email with a link to restore his password

Comment: Do you mean set a password after the admin creates them? Have you looked at https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable at all?

Comment: Please don't use bold text randomly. It's like a spice and using it randomly or too much causes indigestion. Useful headings for separate sections in the text, similar to a reference book, are one thing, but calling out filenames doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You're reinventing the wheel. Devise already has an [Invitable module](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) that does what you are looking for.

After following the installation instructions you just add a link to `new_user_invitation_path` where admins can invite other users. If you want to lock down the invitiations so that only admins can invite users just customize the controller:

```
class MyInvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_action :authorize_admin!, only: [:new, :create]

  def authorize_admin!
    # if you are using Pundit
    authorize resource_class, :invite?

    # or if you're reinventing the authorization wheel
    redirect_to '/somewhere'
  end
end
```

If you really want to reinvent the wheel do it right. Devise does not do password resets in `Devise::RegistrationsController` - neither should you.

Password resets are done in `Devise::PasswordsController`:

```
                               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action                                                               
                    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
                   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
                        user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                      PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                      POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
```

The link in the password reset email is `/users/password/edit`. Which you can see in the [email view](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb).

```
edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token)
```